# How to model Tensors in Redis optimized for slice queries

Tags: redis

I have a rank-3 tensor composed as follows:

```
     t111, t121, t131     t112, t122, t132     t113, t123, t133
T = (t211, t221, t231),  (t212, t222, t232),  (t213, t223, t233)
     t311, t321, t331     t312, t322, t332     t313, t323, t333
```

Indices denote `t(row, column, matrix)`. Each index maps to a JSON blob. For example, at the index `t322` the blob might be `"{10: 1, 102:1, 88: 2}"`. I'd like to know what is the best way to model my data so that I can query subsets (slices) of this tensor efficiently using Redis and get back all JSON blobs that are contained within the slice.

For example, in a typical query I would need to fetch data starting in the second row and the second column to the third row and third column of the third matrix. Using my notation, I'd want data that matches `t(223)-t(333)`. In this example, I'd get back JSON blobs for 4 cells (denoted as **** below).

```
     t111, t121, t131     t112, t122, t132     t113, t123, t133
T = (t211, t221, t231),  (t212, t222, t232),  (t213, ****, ****)
     t311, t321, t331     t312, t322, t332     t313, ****, ****
```

n.b. *queries will never go across matrices (i.e. the third dimension in the slice will always be the same for both the start and end of the query e.g., `t(xx1)-t(xx1), or t(xx2)-t(xx2), or t(xx3)-t(xx3)`).*

I'm new to Redis and don't have a good understanding how best to model this data and query type. Naively, one could just build keys in the form of `t(xxx)` with the JSON blobs as values, then issue a bunch of GET commands to return the matching cells, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this using `ZRANGE` or set intersections? In the naive approach, the cardinality of my key space is ~1M keys.

Can anyone provide any assistance? Thanks.

Comment: did you consider using Redis Modules like RedisJSON or RedisAI? see http://redisjson.io http://redisai.io